# Increase NFC power on an Android device

Tags: android, nfc

The NFC field on the Android devices is quite weak. Compared to dedicated contactless readers you need to place another device or tag in the exact location of the antenna otherwise it won't read.

Is there a way to increase the field or the power output of the NFC chip though any code means?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to increase the RF power.